# NGINX Configuration Issue: Specific Subdomain Not Redirecting Correctly

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm facing an issue with my NGINX configuration, where a specific `if` condition for redirecting domain traffic doesn't seem to be working as expected. My goal is to redirect traffic from `sub1.otherdomain.com` to a particular service running on port 3001 on the same server, but this doesn't seem to be happening. Always returning 403;

I have confirmed that DNS settings are correct, as requests from `sub1.otherdomain.com` are showing up in the NGINX logs. I've also tried simplifying the regex in the `if` statement, but to no avail.

Basically I have an api server (apidomain.com) and nginx working on this server. I just want to pass the request to the app running on the relevant port. If request coming from `sub1.otherdomain.com` then pass to port 3001. If request coming from `sub2.otherdomain.com` then pass to 3002. if neither then return 403.

My NGINX configuration:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name apidomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomaincert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomainprivate.key;

    location / {

        set $allowed_domain 0;

        if ($http_host ~* "sub1\.otherdomain\.com") {
            set $allowed_domain 1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        }

        if ($http_host ~* "sub2\.otherdomain\.com") {
            set $allowed_domain 1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        }

        if ($allowed_domain = 0) {
            return 403; # Unauthorized
        }

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Also I tried but all request from both sub domains are sent to the same port 3001.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomaincert.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomainprivate.key;

    return 403;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub1.otherdomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/cert.apidomaincert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomainprivate.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub2.otherdomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomaincert.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/apidomainprivate.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: Which are the urls to access to subdomains?

Comment: Instead of `if` blocks, use separate [server blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) to handle each subdomain, and include a default server block to handle the `return 403`.

Comment: But the requesting subdomains belong to another domain.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Richard's comment, this is the best practice to handle multiple domains in nginx.

```
# Catch-all domain which returns 403 to all requests if no other server block matches
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/key/for/default; # In this case this could be for apidomain.com
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/for/default;

    return 403;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub1.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/key/for/sub1;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/for/sub1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    ...
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub2.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/key/for/sub2;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/for/sub2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
    ...
}
```

It is best to avoid using `if` whenever possible, as it might not always work as one expects.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in...
Maybe because of no location scope?. When I try with location scope, it always responding by first server scope which is port 3001

Comment: I updated the example by moving `proxy_pass` under `location`. What is the exact request you are doing that gives back response from port 3001 even though it should return response from port 3002?

Comment: Thank you for this. With the config you wrote, when I request from sub1.example, it gives response from 3001 which is correct. But When I request from sub2.example, its still gives response from 3001, but it should be 3002

Comment: Please share the full nginx configuration you have tried in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Nginx but I think your configuration is very similar to the one mentioned in the following article in which they indicate that using if clauses may not be a good idea within a location

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Specifically, take a look at the first example they indicate. It seems to me that the same thing happens to your reverse proxy configuration

try what is mentioned in the “What to do instead” section

Comment: I don't have much experience with Nginx either and I can't say that I understood what was said there, but thank you.